# ASP.NET MVC 4 ActionLink generates URL that contains model name in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an index view in which I'm looping though a collection of models and using ActionLink to create hyperlinks to view, update, delete any given model. I believe I am using one of the most plain-vanilla methods of using the ActionLink. My code looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Details", new { id = person.Id })
```

Note: I've tried this with and without specifying the controller name. It's not going to a different controller, just the one associated with this view.

Here's the problem:  The URL it generates looks like this:

http://localhost:6686/People/Details/PersonDTOs/3

- My controller is "People", so that's OK.
- The action is "Details" so that's OK.
- PersonDTO is the *type* of the model being displayed on the index page.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out *why* ActionLink is tossing the model name into the URL.

I have no custom URLs defined in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Details",, new { id = person.Id })` try this just 1 extra comma

Comment: As you posted it, the answer above does not even compile. However, putting null in between those two commas appears to have done the trick.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: UPDATE to my comment above. Adding the null between the two consecutive commas did cause the (undesired) model type to drop out of the URL. Unfortunately, the "details", and "delete" links now no longer show the "id" number at the end of the URL.  Not quite done yet...

Comment: I found the issue. I am using RavenDB as the database and the documents themselves have a string "id" property of "PersonDTOs/10", which is causing the URL to apear the way that it does.  I am considering this closed.